# Google Apps Script - Passing Variable from a Script to an HTML then back to a Script and one last time to an HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am having troubles passing 1 variable (**dateToExport**) into an HTML "showConflict_HTML" and then running a function/script within that HTML by passing **dateToExport**.

- 1 Script ("exportButton")
- 1 HTML ("showConflict_HTML")

The Process goes like this:

1. The script "exportButton" runs passing (**dateToExport**) into it
2. And then the "showConflict_HTML" html pops up in which the user clicks a button "Yes, Overwrite and Export"
3. The script "exportButton" then runs again and passes the **dateToExport** into it again

When I click the "Yes, Overwrite and Export", nothing happens and the "google.script.run.exportOrderData(1, dateToExport_captured);" does not run in the HTML. Also there is no error given so I can not figure out why. Anyone have any idea why?

```js
function exportOrderData(override, dateToExport) {

     if(override == 1){
        execute_exportOrderData();
        easterEgg = 1;
     }

     else if(override == 0){
        var userInterface = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('showConflict_HTML');
    
        userInterface.dateToExportFromServerTemplate = dateToExport;

        SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
        .showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Existing Customer Order(s) on ' + dateWithConflict);
     }

}
```

```html
<!-- "showConflict_HTML". This HTML file is will run the exportOrderData function once the Override button ("my_button") has been clicked !--> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
    <button id='my_button'>Yes, Overwrite and Export</button>
    
    <script>
      `THIS SHOULD PASS THE dateToExport Varaible so we can access it in this HTML Script`
      var dateToExport_captured = dateToExportFromServerTemplate;

    // Once the Button is Clicked, the following occurs
    document.getElementById('my_button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
      
      // Once the Button is Clicked, the Loading Circle Effect Function will start running here
      google.script.run.loadingCircleEffect();
      google.script.run.exportOrderData(1, dateToExport_captured);


    });
    </script>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

function exportOrderData(override, dateToExport) {

Comment: I'm confused.  You are running `exportOrderData` from the page to display a page with `dateToExportFromServerTemplate` in it.  It seems like a circular reference.

Comment: I see what you mean by circular but would that effect accessing the "dateToExport" in the HTML? Let's say we input (0, "9/10/2022"), then we want to pop up the HTML so a user can click the button "Yes, Overwrite and Export" and then the function runs passing (1, "9/10/2022")

Comment: Your html files contains `<!-- "showConflict_HTML".` which is the same page you are displaying from `exportOrderData` so it looks to me like you are simply redisplaying the page.  Which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Yup, I think I made it more complex that it actually should be but I was able to get what I needed by using "localStorage.setItem('dateToExport_transfer',dt)" from the User's input HTML so I can now access 'dateToExport_transfer'  n "showConflict_HTML"

Answer (score 1):

Try using [force-printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#force-printing_scriptlets) in your HTML, along the lines of this:

```
var dateToExport_captured = <?!= JSON.stringify(dateToExportFromServerTemplate) ?>;
```

Notes:

1. `JSON.stringify` can be omitted if your value is a string or a number.
2. Per the documentation, you should NOT use this technique if `dateToExport` comes from untrusted users. If it's your own system that generates it then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not an answer it may shed some light on what is wrong with your code.

To pass `dateToExportFromServerTemplate` to the html page you need to change the code in `exportOrderData` as below using templated html `createTemplateFromFile`

```
var userInterface = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('showConflict_HTML');
userInterface.dateToExportFromServerTemplate = dateToExport;
userInterface = userInterface.evaluate();
```

For the page to receive the variable you need to use a scriptlet.

```
var dateToExport_captured = <?= dateToExportFromServerTemplate ?>
```

But what I don't understand is `dateToExportFromServerTemplate` never changes so why display a new page?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this by using `localStorage.setItem('dateToExport_transfer',dt)` in the HTML where the user selects the date and then in my "showConflict_HTML" HTML I call `var dateToExport_captured  = localStorage.getItem('dateToExport_transfer')` to grab that date from the other HTML.